# Error creating dynamic table : (array value must start with "{" or dimension information)

Tags: dynamic-sql, greenplum

I am creating a dynamic table in Greenplum.

Below is my code where passing two variables i_colname and i_tablename.

```
v_sql := 'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Updates AS (SELECT A.*,'||i_colname||' AS IS_FLAG FROM '||i_tablename||' A WHERE LOWER(TRIM(a.col12)) = ''rtp'') DISTRIBUTED RANDOMLY';

raise notice '%', v_sql;

execute v_sql;
```

But I am not able to understand why I am getting below error, even the table name I am passing doesn't have any array datatype column. If I remove the i_colname from the dynamic query then its working fine.

> ERROR: (array value must start with "{" or dimension information)
>   SQL state: P0001

Comment: How are you calling the function?  What does the function return?  What datatype is the column?  Does it work if you execute the SQL that is raised by the notice?

Comment: 1. select function_name('value');
2. function return Boolean
3. column datatype Boolean, which is I am getting from input parameter
4. code aborted before executing raise notice when I am binding the sql into variable

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your error so I think it is something you are leaving out of the question.  Here is an example of it working.

```
CREATE TABLE test_table
(
  id integer,
  bar text,
  col12 text,
  bool boolean
)
DISTRIBUTED BY (id);
```

Insert some data:

```
INSERT INTO test_table 
SELECT i AS id, 'foo_' || i AS bar, 
       'rtp'::text AS col12, true AS bool 
FROM generate_series(1, 100) AS i;
```

Create the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_test(p_colname text, p_tablename text)
  RETURNS boolean AS
$$
declare
    v_sql text;
begin
    v_sql := 'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Updates AS (SELECT A.*,' || p_colname || 
             ' AS IS_FLAG FROM ' || p_tablename || 
             ' A WHERE LOWER(TRIM(a.col12)) = ''rtp'') DISTRIBUTED RANDOMLY';

    raise notice '%', v_sql;

    execute v_sql;

    return true;
exception
    when others then
        raise exception '(%)', sqlerrm;
end;
$$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Here is the function in action:

```
gpadmin=# SELECT fn_test('bool', 'test_table');
NOTICE:  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Updates AS (SELECT A.*,bool AS IS_FLAG FROM test_table A WHERE LOWER(TRIM(a.col12)) = 'rtp') DISTRIBUTED RANDOMLY
 fn_test 
---------
 t
(1 row)
```

******* revised question *******

How do you concatenate a boolean in a string?  Answer, you can't.  You have to create a variable that is a string and set the value based on the boolean.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_test(p_tablename text, p_ind boolean)
  RETURNS boolean AS
$$
declare
    v_sql text;
    v_true_false text;
begin
    if p_ind then
        v_true_false := 'true';
    else
        v_true_false := 'false';
    end if;

    v_sql := 'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Updates AS (SELECT A.*,' || v_true_false || 
         ' AS IS_FLAG FROM ' || p_tablename || 
         ' A WHERE LOWER(TRIM(a.col12)) = ''rtp'') DISTRIBUTED RANDOMLY';

    raise notice '%', v_sql;

    execute v_sql;

    return true;
exception
    when others then
    raise exception '(%)', sqlerrm;
end;
$$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Please change the function input parameter order and datatype, I mean 
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_test(p_tablename text,p_colname boolean)
and execute it like this 
SELECT fn_test('test_table','True');
then you will get the error.

Comment: You are trying to do an implicit conversion of text to boolean by passing in 'true' and then you are taking that boolean and trying to convert that back to a string with another implicit conversion.  Why?

Comment: If I even execute it as SELECT fn_test('test_table',True); still it through's error. I only want to create a function into which I can pass boolean value as an input parameter TRUE or FALSE and can use it in dynamic query to create a column.

Comment: You are trying to cast a boolean to a string which is not allowed.  If you insist on passing in a boolean and you want to concatenate this with a string, you will have to create a variable in the function that is a string and set it to 'true' or 'false' based on the boolean you passed in.  Then, you will use the string variable to concatenate the value.

Comment: Look at my revised answer above.